# Como cambiar el color del texto a múltiples groupBox en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito ayuda, soy nuevo en el lenguaje de programación C#
y quisiera acortar el código del formulario.

Cree un formulario con metro Framework, y al cambiar el tema a oscuro(Dark)
los textos de los groupBox de windows form no se ven.
para solucionar los agregue al SelectedIndexChanged.
pero es mucho código, y quisiera llamar a los groupBox desde una clase.
he intentado de todo pero no resulta.

```
    private void metroComboBoxThema_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (metroComboBoxThema.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                metroStyleManager1.Theme = MetroFramework.MetroThemeStyle.Dark;
                groupBoxTema.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox1.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox2.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox3.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox4.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox5.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox6.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox7.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox8.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox9.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox10.ForeColor = Color.White;
                groupBox11.ForeColor = Color.White;

                break;
            case 1:
                metroStyleManager1.Theme = MetroFramework.MetroThemeStyle.Light;
                groupBoxTema.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox3.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox4.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox5.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox6.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox7.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox8.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox9.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox10.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox11.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! esto es wpf o winforms?

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a reponer.mySelf;

lo que quería era recorrer la lista de controles(GroupBox)
con foreach y que el texto de cada GroupBox cambiara de color,
según el tema escogido(Black/Light)

```
public static class ExtencionColor
{

    public static List<T> GetControls<T>(this Control container) where T : Control
    {
        List<T> controls = new List<T>();
        foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
        {
            if (c is T)
                controls.Add((T)c);
            controls.AddRange(GetControls<T>(c));
        }
        return controls;
    }

}
```

usando
this.GetControls().ForEach(p => p.ForeColor = Color.Black);
para el tema Black

y
this.GetControls().ForEach(p => p.ForeColor = Color.White);
para el tema Light